# Use an audio/video file from a Linux laptop via USB to be played by Magic Sing ET-23H

Tags: linux, usb, audio, video

I am one of the technical directors of a regular karaoke contest event. For the karaoke contest itself, due to tight budget, we are using what one of the sponsors are providing - [Magic Sing ET-23H](http://www.magicsing.org/bp/products-page/magic-sing/magic-sing-et-23kh-et-23000h/) . The video output of the Magic Sing ET-23H are broadcasted at two big screens that are being shown to the audience and event attendees.

When a karaoke contestant provides his / her karaoke video, the video itself is in a readable USB flashdrive and is attached to the USB input of Magic Sing ET-23H. What really bugs me is that the interface of Magic Sing ET-23H are also being broadcasted at the big screen video feeds. The interface of choosing the video file is being seen in the Magic Sing ET-23H - also to the big video screens that are seen by the audience and event goers.

I will post in the comments ( if my less than 10 reputation would allow me) the picture of Magic Sing ET-23KH USB input of the device.

I always bring my laptop, [Acer AS5742-7653](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZUXWVQ), during the regular karaoke event. I'm using my laptop also for tallying of scores from the judges, and also playing audio files from contestants that did not provide a karaoke video. I personally am using different Linux distros, but I next to all the time use my Ubuntu Studio 12.04.3 64bit partition during the regular karaoke contest event.

My question is this: Is there a way I can share a temporary video/audio file directly from the laptop I'm using, going to the Magic Sing ET-23H that can broadcast both the video/audio file? Just like how in Window's Avisynth AVS files, or VirtualDub's temporary avi file, or like using ffplay (of ffmpeg), etc.

I have researched somewhat the matter and found links in SuperUser.com. Though I can only provide the links at the comments section of this post if my reputation of less than 10 would allow me.

I have a hunch it is possible, but I have not fully understood the device being used at the event, Magic Sing ET-23H, if there are other ways for it to broadcast video and audio files besides its USB input.

Any help to my current predicament is highly appreciated. Thank you.

PS: Since I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links and also post images, I will try to post the image & links at the comments (if my below 10 reputation would allow me).

Comment: [Here is the image file of the USB input of Magic Sing ET-23H](http://i.imgur.com/n11XuoI.png)

Comment: Here are the SuperUser links I found in my research for my current predicament. [Use a PC as an external drive via USB](http://goo.gl/DrRH2Y) | [Share folder using as an USB mass storage device from a Raspbery Pi](http://goo.gl/goSjEZ) | [Sharing storage partition from Linux device over USB](http://goo.gl/NAWj6J) | [Serve up PC Hard drive as USB Mass storage](http://goo.gl/wmut1E)